# How do I make this preg_match case insensitive?

Tags: php, regex

Consider:

```
preg_match("#(.{100}$keywords.{100})#", strip_tags($description), $matches);
```

I'm trying to show only 100 characters in each side with the search string in the middle.

This code actually works, but it is a case sensitive. How do I make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Just add the **`i`** modifier after your delimiter (`#` in your case):

```
preg_match("#(.{100}$keywords.{100})#i", strip_tags($description), $matches);
```

If your delimiter is `/`, add an `i` after it :

```
preg_match("/your_regexp_here/i", $s, $matches); // i means case insensitive
```

If the **`i`** modifier is set, letters in the pattern match both upper and lower case letters.

Answer (score 8):

Another option:

```
<?php
$n = preg_match('/(?i)we/', 'Wednesday');
echo $n;
```

https://php.net/regexp.reference.internal-options