# preg_grep search with non case sensitive

Tags: php, preg-match, case-sensitive

Is there a chance to search in the preg_grep input with non case sensitive search?

```
$checkAuth = preg_grep("/CN=".$cn_name."/", $entries[0]["member"]);
```

The cn_name can be with upper and lower case, but it works only with the correct case sensitive name. I know, the preg_match can be used with an "i" like:

```
preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")
```

but preg_match requires a string and is not working with a array.

Comment: Why can't you just add the `i` flag to `preg_grep`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I make this preg\_match case insensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411037/how-do-i-make-this-preg-match-case-insensitive)

Comment: possible read preg_grep

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do

```
$checkAuth = preg_grep("/CN=".$cn_name."/i", $entries[0]["member"]);
```

`preg_grep` and `preg_match` both use PCRE patterns