# What does (?i) and ?@ in this regex mean

Tags: regex, splunk

In the following regex what does "(?i)" and "?@" mean?

```
(?i)<.*?@(?P<domain>\w+\.\w+)(?=>)
```

I know that "?" means zero or one and that i sets case insensitivity.

This regex captures domains from an email address in a mailto field, but does not include the @ sign. It was generated the erex command from within SPLUNK 6.0.2

Comment: Are you sure you did not forget any char in the `(?P` part? E.g. `(?:P`?

Comment: That definitely works as quoted.

Comment: @sp00m that is actually part of a named extraction (?P<var>...). It could be specific to SPLUNK.

Comment: This is partially addressed in the [StackOverflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496). Relevant questions: [`*?`:zero-or more with reluctant quantifier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399) (section "Quantifiers", at the top), and [What does the `i` modifier mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12411066), (section "Modifiers", about 1/2 down).

Comment: Splunk is also listed under "General documentation > Official documentation for specific flavors", about 3/4 down.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

demo here : https://regex101.com/r/hE9gB4/1

```
(?i)<.*?@(?P<domain>\w+\.\w+)(?=>)
```

its actually getting your domain name from the email id:

`(?i)` makes it match case insensitive and

`?@` is nothing but `@` which matches the character `@` literally.

the `?` in your `?@` is part of `.*?` which we call as a lazy operator, It will give you the text between the `<` and `@`

if you dont use the `?` after the `.*` it will match everything after `<` to the end. ( we call this as the greedy operator)

Answer (score 3):

? here is the UNGREEDY or LAZYNESS modifier:

> .*?

It means: "*everything is good until the @ character that follows is detected*". Otherwise .* would match everything until the end of the string.

Read about it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: This doesn't explain the `(?i)` at all, or if it does, explains it incorrectly (the `?` in `(?i)` has nothing to do with 'non-greedy'.