# contact form/php case sensitive

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I'm using this contact form which seems to work fine with one exception!
The input field for the email address is case sensitive.
So if you're using a device like an iPad, which automatically capitalizes the first letter of the email address (Name@gmail.com)
The form will not recognize it is a valid email address.
Is there a fix for this?

```
    <title>My basic contact form</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Contact Me</h1>
        </div>
<?php  

        // check for a successful form post  
        if (isset($_GET['s'])) echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">".$_GET['s']."</div>";  

        // check for a form error  
        elseif (isset($_GET['e'])) echo "<div class=\"alert alert-error\">".$_GET['e']."</div>";  

?>  
        <form method="POST" action="contact-form-submission.php" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input1">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="input1" placeholder="Your name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input2">Email Address</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_email" id="input2"        placeholder="Your email address">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input3">Message</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea name="contact_message" id="input3" rows="8" class="span5" placeholder="The message you want to send to me."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>


//contact-form-submission.php



<?php

// check for form submission - if it doesn't exist then send back to contact form
if (!isset($_POST["save"]) || $_POST["save"] != "contact") {
    header("Location: contact-form.php"); exit;
}

// get the posted data
$name = $_POST["contact_name"];
$email_address = $_POST["contact_email"];
$message = $_POST["contact_message"];

// check that a name was entered
if (empty ($name))
    $error = "You must enter your name.";
// check that an email address was entered
elseif (empty ($email_address)) 
    $error = "You must enter your email address.";
// check for a valid email address
elseif (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email_address))
    $error = "You must enter a valid email address.";
// check that a message was entered
elseif (empty ($message))
    $error = "You must enter a message.";

// check if an error was found - if there was, send the user back to the form
if (isset($error)) {
    header("Location: contact-form.php?e=".urlencode($error)); exit;
}

// write the email content
$email_content = "Name: $name\n";
$email_content .= "Email Address: $email_address\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n\n$message";

// send the email
mail ("somename@gmail.com", "New Contact Message", $email_content);

// send the user back to the form
header("Location: contact-form.php?s=".urlencode("Thank you for your message.")); exit;

?>
```

Comment: *"Is there a fix for this?"* - Yes, use [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) presuming you need to have the Email address all in lowercase letters.

Comment: @Fred - Wrong, try the 'i' flag in the regx used to check the email

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix 50% wrong sure...ok, but not completely, least I don't think so. However, and for the life of me, I can't see how an email would be case-sensitive; it just doesn't make any sense. If anything, the standard PHP Email validation is [**FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL**](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) - OP can easily transform the variable to lowercase; or have I misunderstood OP's question?

Comment: The best way would be not to do this stupid kind of validation at all – because your regular expression fails for a lot of valid email addresses. (As to how complex this subject matter actually is, I’d suggest you do a little research.) If you need to validate email addresses in PHP, you should use `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  yea not completely wrong, and I agree filter is a better way to do it.  So I give both of you a +1 :)~ I would agree to the strtolower(), if it was stored in say a database, but the OP is just using it to send an email out, so it doesn't need to be modified just needs to pass the validation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will implement these suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you can use [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) for this, along with your present method.

Change

```
$email_address = $_POST["contact_email"];
```

to

```
$email_address = strtolower($_POST["contact_email"]);
```

and it will transform everything entered to lowercase.

However, I suggest you use [**FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL**](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) to validate Email with.

Example:

```
$email_address = strtolower($_POST["contact_email"]);

if(!filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
  echo "E-mail is not valid"; exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 elseif (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email_address))
```

To

```
 elseif (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email_address))
```

Specially, you want the 'i' flag on the preg_match.  For more information see this answer

[how do I make this preg_match case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411037/how-do-i-make-this-preg-match-case-insensitive)

By the way that is a real ugly regx .. lol ... This is the one I use.

```
 /^[^@]+@[-\w._]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Demo

http://regex101.com/r/zH1iJ2/1