# PHP regex to detect an HTML link to a PDF file

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for some feedback on the below regex string to be used by PHP to detect links to PDF files in a given string.

```
/href=["\']?[^"\'>]+(?:\.pdf)["\']?/
```

This seems to do what I want in cursory tests, but I'm wondering if it needs to be more robust for edge cases. For one thing, it doesn't limit to `<a>` tags, just any element with a `href` attribute containing `.pdf`. Is there anything else I am missing? What about case sensitivity for `.PDF`?

Comment: See [how do I make this preg_match case insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411037/how-do-i-make-this-preg-match-case-insensitive).

Comment: If you want the robust solution use a parser. Then you can target elements, not worry about encapsulation, whitespace, escaping, self-closing, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)