# Regex word match from two groups

Tags: php, regex

My requirement is, I want to match words in a sentence from two groups of words, say the sentence should contain at least one word from group 1 and at least 1 from group 2 as well.

Expression - (football | hockey | cricket) and (ronaldo | messi | kohli | jordan)

The sentence can be -
`Ronaldo is the highest paid player in Football.`

What could be the possible regex for this, language is php.

I tried

`(?=.*\b(cat|dog|rat)\b)(?=.*\b(blue|black|red)\b).*$` It works but is case sensitive.

Comment: Show us your attempts to achieve the same

Comment: I tried this -
(cat|dog|rat)(black|red|blue)

Expected output sentence is -
The cat and dogs are black.

Comment: Does the instance of the firs group will be first too in the sentence?

Comment: No, order can be anything, I just need to match at least one word from two sets.

Comment: @CinCout I tried this - (?=.*\b(cat|dog|rat)\b)(?=.*\b(blue|black|red)\b).*$ It works but is cases sensitive.

Comment: Please edit the question to include all relevant details. Do not post them repeatedly as comments on every post

Comment: I have edited it for you this time. Make sure you do it now onwards.

Comment: Exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12411037/2943403  This page can be safely deleted.  (Certainly not reopened)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

`.*\b(?:ronaldo|messi|kohli|jordan)\b.*\b(?:football|hockey|cricket)\b.* /i`

Note the use of `/i` flag to match case-insensitively.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GCFenu/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 2 regexes, one per group, and then checkfor 2 matches:

For example:

Forst regex: `/(Football)|(Hockey)|(Cricket)/i`

Second regex: `/(Ronaldo)|(Messi)|(Kohli)|(Jordan)/i`

[Demo for the First Regex](https://regex101.com/r/cNYxJE/2)

[Demo for the Second Regex](https://regex101.com/r/InPpkI/2)

Comment: I tried this - (?=.*\b(cat|dog|rat)\b)(?=.*\b(blue|black|red)\b).*$

It works but is cases sensitive.

Comment: The Capital letters can be just in the beginning of the word?