# Regex Character Meaning

Tags: php, regex

Im sure this has been posted before but I am having trouble locating an answer.

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -\.]{1,25}+$/i", ...
```

The regular expression above allows for all alphabetic characters, all numeric characters, and the following (,`-`,`.`). It also limits whatever string we are checking against to max 25 characters total. What I cannot understand is the purpose of `+$/i`. I can find most of those characters in documentation but do not understand why they are needed. The only one I cannot find any information on is `i`.

Edit: I suppose the `$` ties into our use of the `^` character?

Edit2: Thanks to comments below it seems the `i` makes the expression case insensitive. Still looking for information in regards to the other characters.

Comment: `/i` makes the regex case insensitive.

Comment: [Official reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make this preg\_match case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411037/how-do-i-make-this-preg-match-case-insensitive)

Comment: The `-` in a character class should always be first or last. Do not put it in the middle of a character class, that creates a range. The `.` in a character class does not need to be escaped.

Comment: Be aware that ` -.` in a character class matches all characters between space and dot, have a look at an [ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/i` flag at the end of the regex makes the preceding pattern case insensitive.  So actually, you could have just used this:

```
preg_match("/^[a-z0-9 -\.]{1,25}+$/i", ...
```

That is, in `/i` mode, `preg_match` will match `a-z` for both lowercase and uppercase letters, so you need only specify one range.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I will accept this but could you possibly share some information on the other characters?

Comment: The `+` just means one or more or whatever precedes, and `$` means end of the string.