Using preg_replace for bbcodes to convert texts
I'm in the process of upgrading my site's engine. The new version does not support bbcodes, and all my forum posts and articles are created using it.
I want to make a script to convert all text with bbdodes to html. But I've run into a problem and I'm not sure how to proceed. Please take a look at my code and suggest how I can improve it.
Functions:
function bbcodeconvert($text)
{

    $text = " ".$text;

    $bbcodes = array(
        '[b]' => '<strong>',
        '[/b]' => '</strong>'
    );

    foreach($bbcodes as $bbcode => $bbcodehtml)
    {
        $text = str_replace($bbcode,$bbcodehtml,$text);
    }

    $bbcodes2 = array(
        '\\[img\\]([^\\\'\;\?([]*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)\\[/img\\]' => '<img src="\\1.\\2" alt="">',
        '\\[img=([^\\\'\;\?([]*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)\\]([^\\[]*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)\\[/img\\]' => '<a href="\\1.\\2" data-lightbox="spic"><img src="\\3.\\4" alt=""></a>',
        '\\[youtube\\]([^\\([]*)\\[/youtube\\]' => '<iframe width="540" height="320" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\\1?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
        '\\[colleft\\]([^\\[]*)\\[/colleft\\]' => '<div class="colleft">\\1</div>',
        '\\[colright\\]([^\\[]*)\\[/colright\\]' => '<div class="colright">\\1</div>'
    );
        
    foreach($bbcodes2 as $bbcode => $bbcodehtml)
    {
        $text = preg_replace($bbcode,$bbcodehtml,$text);
    }

    return(mb_substr($text,1));
}

function oldparse($text)
{
    global  $sys, $L;

    $text = ' '.$text;
    $code = array();
    $unique_seed = $sys['unique'];
    $ii = 5000;

    $p1 = 1;
    $p2 = 1;
    while ($p1 > 0 && $p2 > 0 && $ii < 5031)
    {
        $ii++;
        $p1 = mb_strpos($text, '[code]');
        $p2 = mb_strpos($text, '[/code]');
        if ($p2 > $p1 && $p1 > 0)
        {
            $key = '**'.$ii.$unique_seed.'**';
            $code[$key]= mb_substr ($text, $p1 + 6, ($p2 - $p1) - 6);
            $code_len = mb_strlen($code[$key]) + 13;
            $code[$key] = str_replace('\t','&nbsp; &nbsp;', $code[$key]);
            $code[$key] = str_replace('  ', '&nbsp; ', $code[$key]);
            $code[$key] = str_replace('  ', ' &nbsp;', $code[$key]);
            $code[$key] = str_replace(
                array('{', '<', '>' , '\'', '"', "<!--", '$' ),
                array('&#123;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&#039;', '&quot;', '"&#60;&#33;--"', '&#036;' ),$code[$key]);
            $code[$key] = "<div class=\"codetitle\">".$L['bbcodes_code'].":</div><div class=\"code\">".trim($code[$key])."</div>"; 
            $text = substr_replace($text, $key, $p1, $code_len);
        }
    }

    $text = sed_bbcode($text);

    return(mb_substr($text, 1));
}

Execution example:
$sql = sql_query("SELECT some_text FROM forum_posts WHERE topicid='$s' LIMIT 1");

     while ($row = sql_fetchassoc($sql)) {
          $post_text = oldparse($row['some_text']);
                            }
$output = "Converted text:$post_text";   

I have no problem with a first part where I use "str_replace", but can't figure out segment with "preg_replace" for more complicated bbcodes. Any suggestions?

"But I've run into a problem and I'm not sure how to proceed." - Can you elaborate on the specific problem?

FYI, instead of loops, you can use arrays as arguments to str_replace() and preg_replace(). It will perform all the replacements simultaneously.

Your regular expressions are all missing the delimiter around the pattern.

@ChrisHaas, the problem is that preg_replace gives an empty result and I don't understand what the problem is, what I need to fix..

@Barmar, thanks, but I don't have enough experience to know exactly what you mean by "missing the delimiter around the pattern". I'm working with the code of the old and new versions of the engine and trying to figure it out along the way.

Any tutorial on the preg_XXX functions in PHP should explain that you need to put a delimiter around the regexp, e.g. the / around '/pattern/'

So change '\\[img\\]([^\\\'\;\?([]*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)\\[/img\\]' to '#\\[img\\]([^\\\'\;\?([]*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)\\[/img\\]#' (I used # here so it wouldn't conflict with the / in [/img])

@Barmar, thank you so much! Now bbcodes from $bbcodes2 are processed correctly, but the regular bbcodes from $bbcodes array are no longer processed. Obviously I'm missing something again, what is it exactly?

I hope you didn't add delimiters in $bbcodes. It's only needed for preg functions, not str_replace().

@Barmar, found it, it was auto-replacement, my bad. I've added some # to first array accidentally :D Thanks again, I was getting desperate, but you helped me solve my problem!

@Barmar, one more thing: now the code replaces bbcodes with lowercase letters only. What do I need to change to make uppercase and lowercase ([URL] and [url] for example) count?

In the regular expressions you can use the i flag. You can use str_ireplace() for case-insensitive str_replace().

@Barmar, Sorry, I don't quite understand: given that $bbcodes2 is handled by preg_replace(), how can I use str_ireplace() in the same array?

You don't. You use the i flag in all the regular expressions in $bbcodes2.

Have you read a tutorial on using regular expressions in PHP, so you understand what I mean by "flag"?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411037/how-do-i-make-this-preg-match-case-insensitive

I understand you're new to this, but surely you can use google. "php case insensitive regular expression" finds the above question and similar ones.

@Barmar, of course I googled all these things, I just haven't figured out how to do it correctly in my code yet. Thanks for the link and your patience, I will read and try to figure it out.
